# Netflix/Hulu system architecture

Tags: netflix

Does anybody know the system architecture of Hulu or Netflix? How do they protect their content? How do they deal with scalability with multi-million concurrent subscribers while maintaining content security? A block diagram will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that even though this article is dated (2011) that the NoSQL approach has been spoken of (and is Datastax's use case on Cassandra) is still relevant today.

http://techblog.netflix.com/2011/01/nosql-at-netflix.html

> Our cloud-based infrastructure has many different use cases requiring structured storage access. Netflix is all about using the right tool for the job. In this post, I’d like to touch on the reasons behind our choice of three such NoSQL tools: SimpleDB, Hadoop/HBase and Cassandra.
>   interesting read